# Enable/Disable legend elements on first load of page in C3 Js chart. Also, managing legend elements enable/disable on the basis of checkbox value

Tags: javascript, angularjs, charts, c3.js

I am not able to disable c3 js chart legend elements on page load. (in chart's config). Also, I have a requirement to enable/disable chart legend elements on the basis of a checkbox value. Tried finding in c3 js docs but couldn't find.

```
                 $scope.cpuChartArea = {
            data: {
                x: 'x',
                columns: [
                    xLabels,
                    data1,
                    data2,
                    data3
                ],
                xFormat: '%m-%d-%Y %H:%M:%S',
                types: {
                    'data 1': 'area-spline',
                    'data 2': 'area-spline',
                    'data 3': 'area-spline',

                }
            },
            point: {
                show: false
            },
            axis: {
                y: {
                    tick: {
                        format: function (d) { return d + "%"; }
                    }
                },
                x: {
                    type: 'timeseries',
                    tick: {
                        //format: function (x) { return x.getFullYear(); }
                        format: '%H:%M' // format string is also available for timeseries data
                    }
                }
            },
            tooltip:{
                format:{
                    title:function (x) { return x.getDate() + "/" + x.getMonth() + "/" + x.getFullYear() + " " + x.getHours()+ ":" + x.getMinutes() },
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: If my answer was correct or helped you please mark it as correct so that other users can judge the quality of the  question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realise that you are using Angular, but in plain JS, the legend for each series can be shown/hidden as

```
chart.legend.show('series id');
```

where you replace 'series id' with one of your y data series, eg 'data 1' in your case.

The working snippet below is a pure JS version based on your chart config. The checkboxes show that the legend for each series can easily be hidden and revealed. If you need assistance understanding the click event let me know - all it does is catch a change to a checkbox and depending on the state show or hide the legend for the series with the matching id.

I hope you can adapt this learning to your Angular case.

```js
var chart = c3.generate(
{
    bindto: '#chart',
    size: {
      width: 600,
      height: 140
    },
  data: {
    x: 'xLabels',
    columns: [
      ['xLabels', '2015-09-17 18:20:34','2015-09-17 18:25:42','2015-09-17 18:30:48'],
     ['data 1', 5,10,12],
     ['data 2', 4,13,17],
    ],
    xFormat: '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', // ### IMPORTANT - this is how d3 understands the date formatted in the xLabels array. If you do not alter this to match your data format then the x axis will not plot! 
    types: {
      'data 1': 'area-spline',
      'data 2': 'area-spline'
    }
  },
  point: {
    show: false
    
  },
  legend: {
      position: 'inset',
  inset: {
      anchor: 'top-left',
      x: 20,
      y: 10,
      step: 2
    }
  },
  axis: {
    y: {
      tick: {
        format: function (d) { return d + "%"; }
      }
    },
    x: {
      type: 'timeseries',
      tick: {
        //format: function (x) { return x.getFullYear(); }
        //format: '%H:%M' // format string is also available for timeseries data
        format: '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S' // how the date is displayed
      }
    }
  }, 
  tooltip:{
    format:{
      title:function (x) { return x.getDate() + "/" + x.getMonth() + "/" + x.getFullYear() + " " + x.getHours()+ ":" + x.getMinutes() },
    }
  }  
})

// this is all about toggling the legends.
$('.checkBox').on('change', function(e){

  if ( $(this).prop('checked')){
    chart.legend.show($(this).attr('id'))
  }
  else {
    chart.legend.hide($(this).attr('id'))
  }

})
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.6.7/c3.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/c3/0.6.7/c3.min.js"></script>

<p>Show legends: <label for='data 1'> data 1 </label><input type='checkbox' class='checkBox' id='data 1' checked='true'/><label for='data 2'>data 2 </label><input type='checkbox' class='checkBox' id='data 2' checked='true'/>  </p>

<div class='chart-wrapper'>
<div class='chat' id="chart"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, did it in a similar way for Angularjs

Comment: Can you make check boxes instead of hover over to select ?